# No redirect back to JsOidc Client when Identityserver4 behind IIS Reverse proxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, identityserver4, openid-connect

Why doesn't IdentityServer4 redirect back to JsOidc clients when behind IIS reverse proxy but other clients work as expected?

**Test setup**

Dowloaded the IdentityServer4.Samples-release

Setup test in VS2017 using \Quickstarts\6_AspNetIdentity

Then added JsOidc client to the solution from \Clients\src\JsOidc

IdentityServer4 working fine (as it should we didn't change anything)

All clients (MvcClient, ResourceOwner, Client and JsOidc) work as expected and authenticate with IdentityServer4 on localhost:5000

All redirects (redirect_uri) from IS4 back to the clients function normally

All API Calls work as expected

**So far so good :-)**

Then we setup IIS as reverse proxy for IdentityServer4 on localhost:5000 with a domain name that has a valid SSL (so no warnings in browsers)

Configured IdentityServer4 to use ForwardHeaders middleware - IE app.UseForwardedHeaders(etc...)

Configured IIS to set relevant server variables (eg HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO, HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT)

The IIS re-write rules in web.config (Updated) :-

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST" value="{HTTP_HOST}" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:5000/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://www.wholesalesolar.co.uk/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Configured IdentityServer4 to use new domain as PublicOrigin in options

Updated all the clients to use new https://mytestdomain.com as authority

Made sure the disco doc used new domain instead of localhost and all re-writes working correctly

Here my Startup.cs class for IdentityServer project

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
        {
            iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
            iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
        });

        // Changed Builder to idsBuilder
        var ids4Builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.PublicOrigin = "https://www.wholesalesolar.co.uk"; // Added this
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            ids4Builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("need to configure key material");
        }

        services.AddAuthentication()
          .AddGoogle(options =>
          {
              options.ClientId = "708996912208-9m4dkjb5hscn7cjrn5u0r4tbgkbj1fko.apps.googleusercontent.com";
              options.ClientSecret = "wdfPY6t8H8cecgjlxud__4Gh";
          });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        // New code
        var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions()
        { 
            ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor |
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto |
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost


        };
        forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
        forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
        app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);
        // End new code

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

**So now with IdentityServer4 behind IIS reverse proxy:-**

Tested the MvcClient on localhost:5002 - Everything ok

Tested the ResourceOwnerClient - Everything ok

Tested the Client client - Everything ok

Tested the JsOidc client - Redirect back to client from IdentityServer4 not working

**More test details for JsOidc**

No errors or warnings in IdentityServer4 log

No console errors or warnings in browsers used to test (Chrome, FF, Edge etc)

Using fiddler we compared the sessions before reverse proxy and after. Apart from the host everything looks the same

Using fiddler we double checked the disco document

To be absoultely sure that IIS was working correctly I changed the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST in IIS to be:-

HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST = 'a_domian_that_doesnt_exist.com' and the IdentityServer failed to re-direct back to the MvcClient

Then change it back to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST= '{HTTP_HOST}' and redirect to MvcClient worked correctly again

**So in summary**

Instead of redirecting back to the JsOidc client host IdentityServer server re-directs back to itself using the correct webpage but incorrect host.

**The login URL (IdentityServer MVC app) looks like this:-**

https://mytestdomain.com/account/login?returnUrl=/connect/authorize/callback?client_id=js_oidc&redirect_uri=http://localhost:7017/callback.html&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&state=blahblah&nonce=blahblah

**The incorrect redirect url (after successfull login) looks like this:-**

https://mytestdomain.com/callback.html#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCIetc...

**The URL should be this:-**

http://localhost:7017/callback.html#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCIetc.....

The test client (from IdentityServer4.Samples-release/Clients/src/JsOidc) uses oidc-client.js library

We also have an angular 6 client that uses https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client library that exhibits the same behaviour

We **only changed** IdentityServer4.Samples-release project code **where absolutley necessary** so we could run these tests

Any help would be much appreciated before all hair is torn out from our heads!

Comment: I really don't understand why would someone down vote this question within minutes of me posting it. Would the person who did this please enlighten me with the his/her reason? Thanks...

Comment: Please remove the sensitive information such as: real client Id, client secret, real domain name,etc when posting to public

Comment: The client id and secret were random strings and not valid values. But thanks for highlighting this

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to stop using IIS and use Nginx instead for the reverse proxy. But we never managed to find out what is specifically different when using IDS4 behind IIS rev proxy and the Oidc client.

More details on what we tested can be found here:-

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2478

Comment: I had the different setup with yours. I don’t use outbound url rewrite because my AspNetCore understand behind proxy and return correct real domain. And I come up which same solution that: cannot use iis+url rewrite+aap for reverse proxy for real production AspNetCore.